# Passing arguments to functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't see anything wrong with this code, but it's not working as expected.

```
function slide(slideIndex, slideDirection) {
    console.log(slideDirection); // outputs 'right'
    $('.slide').animate({slideDirection: '-=940'}, 400);
}    

$(function(){
    $('.prev','.slide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var slideIndex = $(this).closest('.slide').index(),
            slideDirection = 'right';

    slide(slideIndex, slideDirection);
    });
});
```

If I use just the string 'right' in the animate method, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned, using the string 'right' directly in the animate function works just fine. Using that variable in the animate method doesn't seem to work. It is being ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating an object literal with the property called `slideDirection`, you're not using the value of the argument. To do that, you'll need to create an object in 2 steps, separately:

```
var obj ={};//empty object literal
obj[slideDirection] = '-=940';//assign a new property
$('.slide').animate(obj, 400);
```

That should do the trick. Your object, in json format looks like this: `{"slideDirection":"-=940"}` whereas *mine* (or the object created as I explained) looks like this: `{"right":"-=940"}`. The latter is what you need, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Nitpick: "To do that, you'll need to create your object literal in 2 steps" -- if you do so, it's no longer a literal.